# How do I condense a failed list of criteria with return False for the password validation?

Tags: python

```
def isValidPassword(password):
    if (len(password)<=8):
        print("Password must be at least 8 characters or more.")
        return False
    if any(digit.isdigit() for digit in password):
        print("Password must have at least single digit or more.")
        return False
    if any(digit.isupper() for digit in password):
        print("Password must have at least one uppercase letter or more.")
        return False
    if any(digit.islower() for digit in password):
        print("Password must have at least one lowercase letter or more.")
        return False
    return True

def confirmedPassword():
    isSecure = False ; isMatch = False
    password = "" ; reenterPassword = ""
    
    while(isSecure == False): 
        password = input("Enter your password: ")
        isSecure = isValidPassword(password)
    while(isMatch == False):
        reenterPassword = input("\nPlease re-enter your password: ")
        if (password == reenterPassword):
            isMatch = True ; print("Password is confirmed. Thank you.")
            print("The password you entered is approved and safe.")
        else:
            (password == reenterPassword)
            isMatch = False ; print("Password is not confirmed. Please try again.")
confirmedPassword()
```

---

If anyone can please help. It is appreciated. I had a hard time figuring out how to condense a failed list of criteria printed out when I input "ABC" to run the program.

Comment: First of all, your conditions do not do what you seem to think they do. To create a list of errors, you first need to create a list e.g. `error = []`, then append to that list whenever you  encounter an error and at the end of the function return that list of error. If the list is empty `len(errors) == 0` then it's a valid password. Also the variable name `digit` is very confusing as your dealing with characters, not digits, but that's just a side note.

Comment: ***PLEASE*** stop using these outdated password validation conditions. https://xkcd.com/936/

Comment: @Codebling I am assuming this is for some sort of personal project/class assignment. That being said, I also immediately thought of that XKCD when I saw this question.

Comment: @JRose likely, or maybe a project manager decided. Either way, someone needs to stop the madness! Yell at that teacher or PM :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your code to print out all the issues with the password before returning whether or not it is a valid password. I also fixed all of the if statements you had to correctly capture the password issue.

```
def isValidPassword(password):
    valid = True
    if (len(password) < 8):
        print("Password must be at least 8 characters or more.")
        valid = False
    if not any(digit.isdigit() for digit in password):
        print("Password must have at least single digit or more.")
        valid = False
    if not any(digit.isupper() for digit in password):
        print("Password must have at least one uppercase letter or more.")
        valid = False
    if not any(digit.islower() for digit in password):
        print("Password must have at least one lowercase letter or more.")
        valid = False
    
    return valid

def confirmedPassword():
    isSecure = False ; isMatch = False
    password = "" ; reenterPassword = ""
    
    while(not isSecure): 
        password = input("Enter your password: ")
        isSecure = isValidPassword(password)
    while(not isMatch):
        reenterPassword = input("\nPlease re-enter your password: ")
        if (password == reenterPassword):
            isMatch = True
            print("Password is confirmed. Thank you.")
            print("The password you entered is approved and safe.")
        else:
            isMatch = False
            print("Password is not confirmed. Please try again.")
confirmedPassword()
```

Comment: Why line  `(password == reenterPassword)` after `else:`?

Comment: @RadekRojík The honest answer is that I did not really look at the rest of OP's code since it appeared to be functional. I have fixed this and some other oddities.